# Normal and invertible operator's polar decomposition does not belong to $C^* (A)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm studying Conway's Functional analysis, solving problem 8.3.24.

> Give an example of a normal operator $A$ such that the partial isometry in the polar decomposition of $A$ does not belong to $C^*(A)$.

In the above problem, they state that, if $A$ is normal and invertible, then it's polar decomposition belongs to $C^*(A)$. This is easily shown because $A = W(A^*A)^{1/2}$ and $(A^*A)^{1/2} $ is invertible since $A$ is invertible. So, I'm trying that $A$ is not invertible matrix, but cannot find the example. Can you help me?

Comment: The result is true in finite dimensions, so you must look for counter-examples in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.  Try the diagonal operator $A$ on $\ell²$ defined on the standard orthonormal basis by $A(e_{n})  = e_{n}/n$.

Comment: @Ruy I have two question. 1. Why it is true in finite dimension? 2. In your diagonal example, $W(e_n) = e_n$, then why this one is not in $C^*(A)$? I think $1$ matrix is in $C^*(A)$. Sorry for low maturity for C*-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE FINITE DIMENSIONAL CASE**

Let $f$ be the function defined on $\mathbb R$ by
$$
  f(x) = \left\{\matrix{
  \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt x}, & \text{ if } x\neq 0,\cr
  0, & \text{ if } x=0.\cr
  }\right.
  $$
Clearly $f$ is discontinuous, but its restriction to the finite spectrum of $A^*A$ is continuous.  Therefore
$$
  W:= Af(A^*A)
  $$
lies in the C*-algebra generated by $A$ and it is not hard to see that $W$ is indeed the polar part of the polar decomposition of $A$.

**THE INFINITE DIMENSIONAL CASE**

Consider the diagonal operator $A$ on $\ell ^2$ defined on the standard orthonormal basis by $A(e_n)=e_n/n$.  Then $A\geq 0$, so
$A=(A^*A)^{1/2}$, and one has that $W$ is the identity operator.

Since $A$ is a compact operator we have that $C^*(A)\subseteq \mathcal K(\ell ^2)$, so $W$ is not in $C^*(A)$.

Comment: Oh... Thank you very much. I fully understand.